# Do query services like Google Finance and Yahoo Finance go back to correct busted and adjusted trades?

Tags: stocks, trading, historical-data, yahoo-finance, google-finance

Do query services like Google Finance and Yahoo Finance go back to correct busted and adjusted trades?

In other words, should I re-download yesterday's data if I want to be sure my intraday data accounts for trade cancellations and corrections?

Comment: If you need that level of detail, you should probably not be relying on a free service which only promises "best effort" accuracy. If that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Busts are very infrequent, and if an equity were illiquid enough to be affected, the bust cost would be enormous.

For a liquid equity, the amount of busted volume is insignificant except during a flash crash or flash spike.  Then it would be reasonable to redownload.